# Error after removing Connection from SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis

I am updating SSIS package to remove a connection to a web service that no longer exists.

I have removed the Tasks within the package that reference this connection, however when I delete the connection from the Connection Manager I get the following error:

```
The connection "Web Service Manager" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
```

When I search the code in the .xml file I find no reference to this connection and it is not used in the SSIS Logging. Where else can I remove this from as I found no trace of it anywhere.

I am using VS2008.

Comment: Was it a shared connection? Is it maybe referenced in the solution/project files? Its strange that it would state the connection name like that as a deleted connection that is still referenced is usually referred to as its GUID in the error message. The name is only used in the connection itself

Comment: Do you have a configuration file that references the connection?

Comment: @RegBes Yes! I found a Package Config file being used which referenced that connection, removing that has resolved this issue. Thanks for the suggestion I was completely stuck.